# How to render CCK image field within page.tpl.php

Tags: entities, media

I have my image field's array `$node->field_blog_image`, but how do I render it as it does in the `$page['content']`?

The URI confuses me as its simply `public://my_image.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_create_url` to get the path of your image:

```
// $nid is the id of your node
$entity = entity_load('node', array($nid));
$uriImagefromNode = $entity[$nid]->field_image_test_field['und'][0]['uri'];
$urlImagefromNode = file_create_url($uriImagefromNode);
// $urlImagefromNode variable now has the path to the image
```

I hope this information be useful.

Comment: Great, however the image style has been lost! After a little digging I found that `image_style_url('my_image_style', $node->field_my_image['und'][0]['uri'])` did the trick.